# EF6 How to add migrations when using DbMigrator?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Im using DbMigrator in my code:

```
        var config = new Configuration();
        return new DbMigrator(config);
```

it will be used to run Update method upon each application start.

I want to create another migration beside initial one which ALREADY has been applied to database through Package Manager Console. What I get when I try to add new migration through 'add-migration' is this error:

```
Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following explicit migrations are pending: [201612101502537_InitialMigration]. Apply the pending explicit migrations before attempting to generate a new explicit migration.
```

But this migration already applied to database and I can see it! What am I doing worng?

Comment: Use update-database in Package Manager Console

Comment: I get exact same exception about pending migration.